# Using data in an array

Tags: php, arrays, openid, echo, lightopenid

On my php page, I am getting the follow output:

```
Array ( [contact/email] => users_name@email_address.com )
```

This is produced via the following line in the php code:

```
print_r($openid->getAttributes());
```

How do I extract the text `users_name@email_address.com` from that array and stick it into a variable `$strEmail;`?

So when I echo the variable:

`echo $strEmail;`

It should output the following on screen:

`users_name@email_address.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the array to a variable and then you can easily access it:

```
$attributes = $openid->getAttributes();
$strEmail = $attributes['contact/email'];
echo $strEmail; // => users_name@email_address.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you can do:

```
$strEmail = reset($openid->getAttributes());
```

However it's better to suggest as this will work for other cases,too:

```
$attributes = $openid->getAttributes();
$strEmail = $attributes['contact/email'];
```

For more details see the [PHP Manual about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) how to access them.