# How do I get the values from array of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like below:

```
Array
(
    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1309611144:1
        )

    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [banner_url] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://apptivowp.apptivo.com/awp-content/10001/uploads/2011/07/gallery_banner.jpg
        )

    [_yoast_wpseo_focuskw] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [_yoast_wpseo_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )
)
```

How can I get the `banner_url` value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using data in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556364/using-data-in-an-array)

Comment: @Ravichandran: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
$array['banner_url'][0]
```